# how to analyse a project in sonarcloud

Tags: upload, project, code-cleanup, sonarcloud

How to rerun analysis for a particular project in Sonarcloud.on what basis does it analyse the code and the project?

I passed 15+ projects in which only 3 where passed.How can i rectify the other codes and get it verified.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.